# Remove non existing files from [Newest documents] (temp files)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was working on an app to upload files on Sharepoint Online via Microsoft Graph API, and I ended with a bunch of temporary files listed on the "Newest Documents", corresponding to created upload session that weren't finalized.

[image: Newest documents]

Those files are counted in the Items count for the folder, but do not appears in the list of files, nor are listed in the "list of file awaiting check-in".

[image]
[image]

Does anyone knows where I can find them, and/or how to get rid of them?

Edit:
I tried to access the folder with Powershell PnP but it also shows no files:
[image]

and `Get-PnPListItems` return no results.

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi @Zella_msft, did you get any success?